# Animation causing jerk after sometimes and causing lag

Tags: android, animation, delay

The below code is causing some jerk and lag after sometimes, I don't know whats wrong with it.

The code block is to make animation for view within screen randomly

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

    int nextX = random.nextInt(width);
    int nextY = random.nextInt(height);

    animation1 = null;
    animation2 = null;

    animation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(currentView, "x", previousX,
            nextX);
    animation1.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIMING);
    animation2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(currentView, "y", previousY,
            nextY);
    animation2.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIMING);
    set.playTogether(animation1, animation2);
    set.setStartDelay(250);
    set.start();

    previousX = nextX;
    previousY = nextY;
}
```

**LogCat**

```
01-16 17:18:12.237: D/dalvikvm(18091): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1451K, 15% free 9621K/11207K, paused 2ms+2ms
01-16 17:18:27.209: D/dalvikvm(18091): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1825K, 18% free 9639K/11655K, paused 1ms+3ms
01-16 17:18:41.926: D/dalvikvm(18091): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1801K, 18% free 9661K/11655K, paused 2ms+2ms
```

Comment: Can you add log for the time you are experiencing lag/jerk plus you are requesting for GC which may cause lag if it runs.

Comment: brother will you tell where are you apply this animation on listview ??

Comment: @RavindMaurya am applying for a button.

Comment: @SunnyKumarAditya the lag is causing around after 10 seconds

Comment: I think your call to system.gc() is causing lag, as it's not recommended to call manually in official docs

Comment: Sorry i removed it already, i was checking using that, But still remains same

Comment: Add the log file also to your question

Comment: Theres no crash , So why are you asking log

Comment: I wan to see if there are logs like 04-22 16:21:30.685: D/dalvikvm(967): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1545K, 20% free 7019K/8720K, paused 78ms+17ms, total 360ms

Comment: yeah i just updated a bit

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your lags can be these GC calls you have in your log.

> **GC_CONCURRENT** Invoked when the heap gets too large to prevent
>   overflow.
>
> The time showed **paused 2ms+2ms** - indicates how much time it took the
>   GC to finish collection

I will suggest dump your hprof file,convert it and analyze it through MAT to identify your memory accumulation points. Find below a really good  article on how to do so.

http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Memory-Profiler-Identifying-Potential-Problems